# Java: How to copy an object so it will be from the same subclass?

Tags: java, oop, reflection

I try to use a simple example for better undersanding: I've got a class `Tool` and child classes which are extending class `Tool`: `Hammer`, `Saw`. Both have defined some fields like `weight` and both are overriding method `getCost` with own implementation.

```
    Tool first_tool = new Hammer();
    Tool second_tool = new Saw();
```

I need a method in `Tool` class, that will to do a copy of any tool, such way, that `first_tool_copy` is from the same subclass as `first_tool`. How can I make this possible? I need something like:

```
    /* Copy tool, change parameters of copy, the original won't change */
    /* first_tool_copy will be instance of Hammer class */
    first_tool_copy = first_tool.copy
    first_tool_copy.weight = 100
```

Conclusions: I would like to have some simple copy constructor common for all subclasses.

Comment: A superclass cannot know all its subclasses, so the only way to achieve this would be via reflection. Why not simply implement the standard `clone()` in all subclasses? If you want, you can even declare `Tool` abstract and so *force* all subclasses to implement `clone()`.

Comment: Thanks, I am also thinking about abstract method, but I would like to avoid implementing the copy for each subclass, because the copy is same for all of them. Maybe I should mention, that the copy is made just by copying the weight attribute.

Comment: Is the `weight` field stored in `Tool`, or is there at least a method on each subclass that returns the `weight`?

Comment: weight is stored in Tool. Each subclass differs by own implementation of getCost, which I would like to preserve for the copied Tool

Comment: @teepee - see my answer for an improvement on Matt Ball's first method using covariance, if you decide not to use reflection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make `Tool` abstract, and add an `abstract copy` method to `Tool`. Then each subclass is forced to provide its own implementation. This is a fairly OO approach, and takes advantage of dynamic dispatch.

```
abstract class Tool
{
    // snip...
    public abstract Tool copy();
    // snip...
}

class Hammer
{
    // snip...
    public Tool copy()
    {
        Hammer h = new Hammer();
        // copy fields from this to h
        return h;
    }
    // snip...
}
```

Otherwise, you'd provide a concrete implementation in `Tool` which you'd have to update every time to want to handle a new subclass of `Tool`. This method would have to use `instanceof`, `getClass()`, or similar non-OO techniques to create the right class. Ew.

---

Remember what [*Effective Java* Item 10 tells us: **Override `clone` judiciously.**](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf)

---

> I should mention, that copy is made just by copying the weight attribute.

Assuming the `Tool` implementation looks something like the below class, you *could* do this with reflection:

```
class Tool
{
    // ...

    public Tool () {}

    public int getWeight ()
    {
        // don't care about implementation
    }

    public void setWeight()
    {
        // don't care about implementation
    }

    // ignores all exceptions - not production code!
    public Tool copy() throws Exception
    {
        Tool copy = this.getClass().getConstructor().newInstance();
        copy.setWeight(this.getWeight());
        return copy;
    }

    // ...
}
```

I wouldn't recommend this, though. It's just smelly and ugly to me.

Comment: Thank you. I agree, that this could by a good OO approach. But I would like to avoid implementing the copy for all subclasses. I should mention, that copy is made just by copying the weight attribute.

Comment: See my edit for a single method implementation on `Tool` which uses reflection.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the perfect minimal answer for me. Combination of getClass() and newInstance()

Comment: @teepee: But in a long term that `copy` method could be misleading.

Comment: see my answer for an improvement on the first method using covariance

Answer (score 5):

There are possibly many solutions for this case, but I believe the simplest one would be using reflection to create the cloned object and copy the fields from the original to the copy. The only requirement this code has is that your subclasses must have a default constructor, but this doesn't look like a real issue anyway.

Here's how it would look like:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Tool implements Cloneable {

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public Object clone() {

    try {

        Tool instance = this.getClass().newInstance();

        List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();

        Class<?> kind = this.getClass();

        while ( kind != null ) {
            fields.addAll( Arrays.asList( kind.getDeclaredFields() ) );
            kind = kind.getSuperclass();
        }

        for ( Field field : fields ) {
            field.setAccessible(true);

            int mod = field.getModifiers();

            if ( !Modifier.isStatic( mod ) && !Modifier.isFinal( mod ) && !Modifier.isNative(mod) ) {
                Object value = field.get( this );
                field.set(instance, value);
            }

        }

        return instance;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(e);
    }

}

}
```

And here's your subclass, that would not have anything special:

```
public class Saw extends Tool {

private int weight;

public int getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public void setWeight(int weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

}
```

And a JUnit test case showing how it would work:

```
public class SawTest {

@Test
public void testClone() {

    Saw original = new Saw();
    original.setName("Some saw");
    original.setWeight( 10 );

    Saw clone = (Saw) original.clone();

    Assert.assertTrue( original != clone );
    Assert.assertTrue( original.getClass().equals( clone.getClass() ) );
    Assert.assertEquals( original.getName(), clone.getName() );
    Assert.assertEquals( original.getWeight(), clone.getWeight() );

}

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a more complex version of solution from Matt Ball. He was first, but this looks very useful for more difficult cases. It will rest in my mind. Thanks for your effort

Comment: This is a more generic and low-maintenance solution. If any class is later expanded, this will still work. Matt Ball's solution won't.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a specific copy for all the subclasses (what is fair enough), you have to use reflection. And if you are ok using reflection, you may want to use [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/).

I would have a utility class, say CopyUtil and a copy method in it to copy an object (using BeanUtils). For some reason if you *need* the copy method as an instance method of Tool, just write one and call this utility method from there.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to build off of the first part of Matt Ball's answer and mention that, since Java 5, return type covariance is supported. What this means is that a child class can override a method by returning a more specific type. This would allow you to do the following:

```
abstract class Tool
{
    public abstract Tool copy();
}

class Hammer
{
    @Override
    public Hammer copy()
    {
        Hammer h = new Hammer();
        // copy fields from this to h
        return h;
    }
}

class Saw
{
    @Override
    public Saw copy()
    {
        Saw s = new Saw();
        // copy fields from this to s
        return s;
    }
}
```

So, when you're working with an assortment of `Tool` objects, you know you can call `copy()` and get `Tool` back. When you're working with only `Hammer` objects, you know `copy()` will return a `Hammer` (cast is not required).